# Why don't first world universities commonly have biomedical engineering at B.S level

Tags: university, bachelor

Our teacher in an image processing class at my local University said that there is no biomedical B.S degree  in top University of first world countries ( based of his last resident in USA and his experiences at there).

Also i think he was trying to mention separation for B.S student to some fields like Biomedical engineering is not common in these universities ( USA' universities).

I searched on Google and found formal biomedical department at some universities like [this](https://be.mit.edu/academic-programs/current-undergraduate) :

> Completion of the curriculum leads to a Bachelor of Science in
>
> Biological Engineering and prepares students for careers in diverse
>
> fields ranging from the pharmaceutical and biotechnology industries to
>
> materials, devices, ecology, and public health.

So I asked here,  is  this degree common in these universities spatially as  B.S graduation

level, or this filed of studies graduate as  B.S electrical engineer without any mention to B.S of biomedical engineering?

**Update:**

Based of  @Charles_E_Grant comment I I think he was saying this field is not common in the USA University, because of letting the student of B.S level find themselves ways and chosing their field on the upper level like M.S or PhD which could be Biomedical engineering. So asked to know is that true.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, your question is difficult to understand, particularly the title. Can you edit it to clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: Since a Google search would reveal a number of such programs in the US, the question needs clarification at the very least.

Comment: Your teacher is simply incorrect, or there has been a misunderstanding. Here is a [list of over a dozen undergrad  bio-medical engineering programs in the US](https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/engineering-doctorate-biological-biomedical). Those are just the programs that also offer a Ph.D. program. Perhaps your teacher meant that biomedical engineering is not typically offered at 4-year undergraduate only colleges. Biomedical engineering programs typically operate in cooperation with both an engineering school and a medical school, which is going to limit it to larger universities.

Comment: I confused  @Charles_E_Grant I think he was saying this field is not common in the USA University, because of letting the student of B.S level find themselves ways and chosing their field on the upper level like M.S or PhD which could be Biomedical engineering. So asked to know is that true

Comment: @moden since I provided you a list of over a dozen universities that offer undergraduate degree specifically in biomedical engineering, so I'd say their starting premise is simply wrong, regardless of what they attributed it too. Note that the list was not exhaustive, it was simply one opinion on the highest ranked programs. To be sure, it's less common than a business degree, but then any engineering degree is less common than a business degree.

Comment: Many (if not most) four year colleges in the US don't offer any engineering degree program.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't my field, but I can give a few reasons why a program might be rare.

Some programs are very expensive to run, requiring specialized laboratories and faculty. This may be the case for biomedical engineering. It is difficult to run such programs for undergraduates because when any student drops out of the program for any reason, it is impossible to replace them. Medical school in the US has this issue. Thus, universities want to run such expensive programs having some assurance that the students are already somewhat prepared at entry and have an initial strong commitment to finishing the program. A few top universities with a lot of access to grant funding (say, MIT) might want to risk it.

But a second reason that some programs are rare is that there are alternative paths into a desirable field and a more general background at entry might be a good thing. Again, medicine in the US is normally (but not exclusively) a graduate level program. Future medical doctors start out in some other field, perhaps biology or chemistry. And some fields, such as psychiatry require so much broad knowledge in addition to the specialization that the specialization can start rather late when students have already seen quite a lot of the needed background.

Comment: This question has a problem: I don't think that these degree programs are actually rare. I think the questioner (or more correctly, the person they cite) are simply not well informed.

Comment: I agree with @WolfgangBangerth that the question is based on a false premise. Moreover, the part about med school is very US specific and has little relation with BSc in biomedical engineering, which are relatively commonly offered in Europe (and I guess in the US from comments to the question).

Comment: @fqq, certainly the US and EU/UK systems are very different. Especially at the undergraduate level. But the OP didn't give a location, and the reference given is to a US institution. And, as I said, it isn't my field so the answer is about expensive-to-deliver programs more than specifically biomedical engineering.